# Entity interpolation not being smooth at higher server send frequency

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking

I am using Unity and Riptide. Riptide is used to send packets between client/server.

What I want to achieve is a smooth transition between the different position states of other players. I don't have any server authority. Clients send their positions and the server redirects them to the other connected clients.

The clients send their positions to the server at a consistent frequency, and the server sends positions of clients to all clients at another, slightly lower, frequency.
At the moment it's only really smooth when I use low send frequency for the server, such as 0.5 seconds. When testing with higher frequency, e.g. 0.1s, there is some amount of lag/jitter/bounciness. It makes the player seem to not have constant acceleration, and so makes it not look as it should.

I have read about entity interpolation [here](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Source_Multiplayer_Networking#:%7E:text=tickrate%20is%2011.-,Entity%20interpolation,-By%20default%2C%20the), and also [here](https://gabrielgambetta.com/entity-interpolation.html#entity-interpolation:%7E:text=in%20marine%20navigation.-,Entity%20interpolation,-There%20are%20some). And below is an implementation for interpolating all the players client side.

```
// called when a new position packet arrives from the server
void UpdatePlayerPositionBuffer(int id, Vector2 newPosition) {
    Player player = null;
    ClientManager.Instance.OtherPlayers.TryGetValue(id, out player);
    if (player != null) {
        player.PositionBuffer.Add((Time.time, newPosition));
    }
}

// called every frame by unity. Time.time is the total elapsed time
void Update() {
    // interpolationDelay is set to double server send rate as recommended by valve
    float renderingTime = Time.time - interpolationDelay;
    
    foreach (Player p in ClientManager.Instance.OtherPlayers.Values) {
        while (p.PositionBuffer.Count >= 2 && p.PositionBuffer[1].time <= renderingTime) {
            p.PositionBuffer.RemoveAt(0);
        }

        if (p.PositionBuffer.Count >= 2) {
            float t0 = p.PositionBuffer[0].time;
            float t1 = p.PositionBuffer[1].time;

            bool inbetween = t0 < renderingTime && t1 > renderingTime;
            if (!inbetween) {
                continue;
            }

            Vector2 p0 = p.PositionBuffer[0].position;
            Vector2 p1 = p.PositionBuffer[1].position;

            p.Position = Vector2.Lerp(p0, p1, (renderingTime - t0) / (t1 - t0));
            spawner.GetPlayerObject(p.Id).transform.position = p.Position;
        }
    }    
}

public class Player {
    public int Id;
    public Vector2 Position;
    public List<(float time, Vector2 position)> PositionBuffer = new();

    public Player(int id, Vector2 position) {
        Id = id;
        Position = position;
    }
}
```

Here is a video showcasing the problem: [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mPo9_Ws9PCy3XqdzMZhv-dkEmaqbDV7b/view)

The red squares are the players. The one with the white dot is the local player for that instance. As you might be able to see - the local player is moving smoothly while the other is lagging.

If you by any chance think you know what the problem may be please tell.

Answer (score 1):

As this was cross-posted to gamedev.net, I'll just post a link to the answer there:
https://www.gamedev.net/forums/topic/714912-entity-interpolation-not-being-smooth-at-higher-server-send-frequency/5459151/